# How to modify the size of String Pool in JVM?

Tags: java, string, jvm, heap-memory, string-pool

I was reading a book on Java and there was an option mentioned to modify the size of the String Pool, and that option was **XX:StringTableSize**. When I tried this in my command line, I got an error saying this is an invalid flag, I tried both of the following and the same error occurred:

> error: invalid flag: -XX1234

> error: invalid flag: -XX:1234

What is the error? I couldn't find a solution for this in the Java SE reference, even I did not see any option like "-XX".

What is the reason behind that, did I made a syntactical error or this option is deprecated or something else? **I am using JDK 11**.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question, e.g., how the command you've used look like.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably passing less than the minimum value allowed. For e.g I can successfully run below on OpenJDK 11

```
java -XX:StringTableSize=16777216 TestClass
```

You can also refer to excellent link [here](https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_openjdk11.html) for summary of different VM options available in different JDK releases.

If I provide less than what is allowed, I get this

```
java -XX:StringTableSize=10 TestClass

uintx StringTableSize=10 is outside the allowed range [ 128 ... 16777216 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'StringTableSize=10'
```

In past there has been discussions on the usefulness and correctness of such parameter support. You can read about these [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8002329).

Comment: So I was using the option at compile-time, and it is used at runtime, as I was using it wth "javac" and it is used with "java" command(i.e. at runtime)

Comment: That's right - it's for runtime. Also please mark this answer as accepted as a good practice on SO :-)